# in this case self denote to which class.....DGcontroller class ya DMcontroller class

Tags: objective-c

@implementation DMcontroller

-(void)presentsecondviewcontroller
{

DGcontroller *secondvg=[[DGcontroller alloc] init];

[secondvg setDelegate:self];
// above self is representing which class

[self presentViewController:secondvg animated:YES completion:nil]; 
// above self representing to which class

}

Comment: If you're inside an instance method in the implementation of `DMcontroller` then that's the class of the `self` object.

Comment: there are two self ....so which one represent to which class..????

Comment: `self` is a symbol that holds a pointer to an object; it doesn't change unless you change it.  Try `NSLog(@"self is %@", self);` and see the result.

Comment: ok this mean that here setDelegate:self represent to DGcontroller class and below self represent to current class,that in this case DMcontroller class

Comment: No, while you're inside a method implementation there's only one `self` unless you do something odd to change it.

Comment: not getting u....there are two self in method implementation one with [Secondvg setDelegate:self] and other one with[self presentviewcontroller] so upper self act like it is DGcontroller class and below self act like it is class of DMcontroller??

Comment: There is only one `self`.  It doesn't become something different because you reference it twice.  It's like saying y = x + 5, z = x + 8.  x isn't two different things because I typed it in two equations.

Comment: @interface NSString (movies)
-(void)movie{
if(self hasprefix:@"mp4")
NSLOG(@"this is string");

}

st=@"ab.mp4";
[st movie];

then in this case self is denote to st object not NSString????

Comment: Assuming that's a category on NSString, therefore it's an implementation of NSString, therefore `self` would be an NSString instance.

Comment: but when movie pass a message to st object this will show the message this is string....then why he say that...??? bec self represnt to current class that is working on ,so in this case st object which has string @ab.mp4

Comment: For the last time, if you want to know what `self` is inside any method, use this: `NSLog(@"self is %@", self);` or better `NSLog(@"self is a %@", [self class]);`.